# How can i export list of urls in excel sheet shorten using goo.gl?

Tags: google-url-shortener

I have a list of urls shorten using goo.gl. Now i want to export them to excel sheet or PDF. Is there any way to do to this.

Comment: I don't understand, you want to export the URL itself or the webpages (captured as image)?

If you just want the urls in excel, you could use regexp to create a .csv file which excel should be able to read fine. I use Notepad++ to do this kind of work.

Answer (score 0):

Three steps and I am not kidding.

- Go to details page of the shortened URL
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
- then paste it in your favourite app